# How to save a file from database to server in php

Tags: php, mysql, opentbs

I have a database table to store my templates(.docx file). I am using openTbs to work on that templates.My need is that to take out the template and store it in thee server itself, and edit using openTbs.

My question is that how I can retrieve .docx file from database and store that in the server side.?  (The storing may be temporary but i want to edit it using openTbs.)

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Why are you saving the .docx in the database? Couldn't you just store them in a folder?

Comment: In my case there is lot of templates and I thing it is better to store in the database for avoid space lose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to save binary data in the database, mostly when this data are intend to be processed by a file server, such as pictures or your DOCX.

Anyway, since OpenTBS 1.8.1, you can open an DOCX (or any Ms Office, LibreOffie or zip archive) from a PHP file handle.

You can use this feature to easily merge your template from the database :

```
// retrieve binary data of the file
$rs = mysql_query($dbc, "SELECT data FROM files WHERE id=$id");
$rec= mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysql_free($rs);

// create a temporary file
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $rec['file']);
unset($rec); // free PHP memory

// Open the file with OpenTBS
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
$TBS->LoadTemplate($temp);
...
```